# Angular controller not working after window.history.pushstate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
  $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:55090/login/login',
        }).success(function(data){
            // With the data succesfully returned, call our callback
            $("html").html("");
            debugger           
            $("html").html(data);
            window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/login/login");                
        }).error(function(){
            alert("error");
        });
```

Above code is working, i am able to load the data of another page without refreshing but the the thing is i am using two different angular for both pages.
As soon as i load another html, all the functionality(including models,directives) stopped working.

Comment: Could you provide a Plunkr of jsFiddle of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 differents pages the 2nd will probably have his own angular injector created with the ng-app attribute. So you won't have the service/controller of the 1st page.

Angular is meant to be single page application and not to be used with jQuery like this. If you want to perform some navigation check `ngRoute`or `ui-router`on the net.

If you need to add some HTML at a specificed location check `$compile` and `angular.element` even though it's not recommanded.

Comment: Okay thanks @walfrat.. I am a beginner in the angular.

Comment: Then here's is my advice : forget jQuery. Just learn the basics with full angular code. You lay need jQuery latr on when you'll want to write directives, but you have some way to go before doing this.